# Method for Parallel Aligning Paragraphs in Two-Column Webpage at Scale

Tags: html, css, formatting

I am looking for an effective method to align paragraphs of a large bilingual text in a two-column website on the large scale. My document is a very long text. The webpage will have two columns each taking 50 % of the page. The first column will have the document in English; the second column will have the same document in German. Each paragraph will need to have a blank line between them, and the first line of each paragraph must line up with the corresponding paragraph in the other language.

I have worked out a method styling paragraphs as boxes using the following as an example of what I have done:

**HTML for First Paragraph (used for both English and German sides):**

```
<div id="box1">

        I.
        <br>

        <p>THE SCIENTIFIC LITERATURE ON THE
PROBLEMS OF THE DREAM
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS for First Paragraph (used for both English and German sides)**

```
#box 1 {
    height: 175px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #162e2e;
    
  }
```

The above solution will align paragraphs very well due to the specified height of the box. I use the same height for corresponding paragraphs and therefore the paragraphs take up exactly the same amount of space, however, this would be very difficult to do at scale. It would require calibrating every paragraph of the document individually. Are there other ways to do this which would be effective at scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have each paragraph in separate `div` with a class of let's say `paragraph`.

```
<div class="paragraph">
  ...
<div>
```

Each `div` will have two children, one for english text and other for german text. We can apply `display: flex` to this `div` so that the paragraphs are side by side.

```
<div class="paragraph" style="display: flex">
     <p>English Text</p>
     <p>German Text</p>
</div>
```

Then for the children, We can apply `flex: 1 1 50%` which means, each child will have a width of `50%` and will `grow` and `shrink` in equal proportions.

```
<div class="paragraph" style="display: flex">
     <p style="flex: 1 1 50%">English Text</p>
     <p style="flex: 1 1 50%">German Text</p>
</div>
```

Separating the `HTML` and `CSS`, we get this:

```css
.paragraph {
  display: flex;
}

.paragraph > p {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Deutsches Ipsum Dolor id latine Wiener Schnitzel complectitur pri, mea meliore denique Wurst id. Elitr expetenda nam an, Bier ei reque euismod assentior. Odio Currywurst iracundia ex pri. Ut vel Bretzel mandamus, quas natum adversarium ei Wiener Schnitzel diam minim honestatis eum no. Deutsches Ipsum Dolor id latine Wiener Schnitzel complectitur pri, mea meliore denique Wurst id. Elitr expetenda nam an, Bier ei reque euismod assentior. Odio Currywurst iracundia ex pri. Ut vel Bretzel mandamus, quas natum adversarium ei Wiener Schnitzel diam minim honestatis eum no.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Deutsches Ipsum Dolor id latine Wiener Schnitzel complectitur pri, mea meliore denique Wurst id. Elitr expetenda nam an, Bier ei reque euismod assentior. Odio Currywurst iracundia ex pri. Ut vel Bretzel mandamus, quas natum adversarium ei Wiener Schnitzel diam minim honestatis eum no</p>
    <p>Deutsches Ipsum Dolor id latine Wiener Schnitzel complectitur pri, mea meliore denique Wurst id. Elitr expetenda nam an, Bier ei reque euismod assentior. Odio Currywurst iracundia ex pri. Ut vel Bretzel mandamus, quas natum adversarium ei Wiener Schnitzel diam minim honestatis eum no. Deutsches Ipsum Dolor id latine Wiener Schnitzel complectitur pri, mea meliore denique Wurst id. Elitr expetenda nam an, Bier ei reque euismod assentior. Odio Currywurst iracundia ex pri. Ut vel Bretzel mandamus, quas natum adversarium ei Wiener Schnitzel diam minim honestatis eum no.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this satisfies your needs!.

Edit: Added borders to see the distinction between the two texts.

Comment: Perfect, and clearly explained! Thank you very much.